# HTTPS block my audio playlist. How to solve it?

Tags: javascript, https, playlist

I created my first website and I'm trying to correct all my problems.
I have a file javascript which can play songs automatically (audio playlist).
It works on my computer and it worked when I uploaded my website without the extension "https".

Now, I securised my website and when I want to play my audio playlist, at the end of a song, it didn't go to the next song. Moreover, I'm redirected on the file (it leaves my principal page).
I really don't understand this problem and I'm not enable to solve it alone.

Do you know if I can do something with my .htacess file or in my javascript file ?
Thanks you in advance for your answers.

NB: This is my javascript file and my website to see the problem: https://www.oldgamesheetmusic.org/Scores

```
var audio;
var playlist;
var tracks;
var current;
init();
function init(){
    current = 0;
    audio = $('audio');
    playlist = $('#playlist');
    tracks = playlist.find('li a');
    len = tracks.length;
    audio[0].play();
    playlist.find('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        link = $(this);
        current = link.parent().index();
        run(link, audio[0]);
    });
    audio[0].addEventListener('ended',function(e){
        current++;
        if(current < len){
            link = playlist.find('a')[current];  
            run($(link),audio[0]);  
        }
    });
}
function run(link, player){
    player.src = link.attr('href');
    par = link.parent();
    par.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    audio[0].load();
    audio[0].play();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html includes

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
```

on a https site, http requests are blocked

try

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
```

without http or https the request will be made with the protocol used by the page, e.g. https if the page is https

Once you fix that - your code may run - though your request for `playlist.js` fails and there's `a 403 error when trying to use ErrorDocument` - so the 403 is when trying to use ErrorDocument, but the error for getting `playlist.js` may be different

Comment: Thanks you for your comment ! I put the javascript file in my html page. It works. However, everyone can read my codes... It's not the best solution but for now, I have this way.

Comment: @Helpme 'everyone can read my codes" - what? Yes, that's how the internet works - you want people to visit your site, then they can see your "codes"

Comment: Not necessary. Yes, you can read my html pages, but I had a solution to not see my javascript file (through my .htacess file). Now, I put my javascript file on my html page. So, yes, people can read my lines.

Comment: yes, that's how browsers work, they need to read the javascript files ... and once the javascript files are in the browser, anyone can see them

Answer (score 0):

Your playlist.js isn't getting loaded because of a 403, and it looks like your jQuery is also blocked.

Comment: Thanks you for your comment ! I put the javascript file in my html page. It works. However, everyone can read my codes... It's not the best solution but for now, I have this way.

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.